# Coded UI Tests don't run on one machine, but run on another

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My co-workers and I are working on a Coded UI project. We both have the same version of the project thanks to TFS, but on his computer all the test cases run, and on mine they don't. They used to run perfectly fine on my machine until one morning they decided to not work. I always keep getting the same error that the UI Test Controls are not found, even though the mappings are correct. Let me remind you that they work perfectly fine on my co-workers machine. We also have the same version of IE (11).

What could be the cause for this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Which language and what error exactly?

Comment: I'm using C# and the error is UI Test Control not found. But the error is not really the problem. It says that the mapped control could not be found, even though all the search properties match, and they work for my co-workers that have the same set up I do. The problem is that test cases that are known to be executed successfully without errors, simply don't run with the error mentioned above. We all have the same version of the code because we pull it from TFS (source control).

Answer (score 1):

My co-worker seemed to resolve the situation, but we still don't understand why the previous version of the code worked for everyone but my machine. The problem occurred in our LaunchBrowser method which would use 2 different instantiations of the browser variable. He got rid of the unnecessary one and the playback commands and seemed to have fixed the problem.

Below are two versions of the code, the previous one and the newly written one:

Old:

```
public static void LaunchBrowser(string url)
        {
            GlobalVariable.browser = new BrowserWindow();
            CloseAllBrowsers();
            BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = GlobalVariable.BrowserType;

            Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;
            GlobalVariable.browser = BrowserWindow.Launch();
            System.Uri URI = new System.Uri(url);
            GlobalVariable.browser.NavigateToUrl(URI);
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
            GlobalVariable.browser.Maximized = true;
            if (BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser == "Firefox")
            {
                Mouse.Click(_fireFoxAuthOK);
            }
            Logging.WriteLog("Browser was navigated to " + url + " in browser: <" + GlobalVariable.BrowserType + ">");
        }
```

New:

```
public static void LaunchBrowser(string url)
        {
            CloseAllBrowsers();
            BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = GlobalVariable.BrowserType;
            GlobalVariable.browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(url));
            GlobalVariable.browser.Maximized = true;
            if (BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser == "Firefox")
            {
                Mouse.Click(_fireFoxAuthOK);
            }
            Logging.WriteLog("Browser was navigated to " + url + " in browser: <" + GlobalVariable.BrowserType + ">");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line :

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
```

Because the browser's foreground thread is not ready to start the playback. you may try this

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;
```

or different alternative ways in your pc.

Refer this link [Mathew Aniyan's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/08/10/configuring-playback-in-vstt-2010.aspx) for further information.

Comment: Setting the WaitForReadyLevel to UIThreadOnly means that the test will wait for the browser to finish loading before continuing (as stated in the blog post you linked to).  By disabling it, the method should still pass since you're not interacting with the browser other than to send a new URL to navigate to (no clicks, text editing, etc.).  However, once you pass this method, if the setting is still disabled, you could encounter errors when attempting to interact with objects on the page.  The main issue here is the double instance of the BrowserWindow() object.

Comment: Thanks Rayn cox, This is just my suggestion to check why the test is not running the different pc.